# A text animation tool or plugin pack that has very elaborate text animations?

Tags: premiere, animation

I *dont* want to do the animations by hand myself. The idea is that I use something that already exists and just slap my text inside. Manually doing all these elaborate animations is not an option for me.
It doesn't need to be exactly like in the photo e.g. text gets written out, then erased afterwards. But some plugins or packs or whatever will do just fine. Thing is, I googled for a long time now, never saw something similar.
Am I googling for the wrong tool (adobe premiere pro)?

here an example how the text pops out:

[image]

then another example where it goes away again:

[image]

the idea is that the text animations are interesting. They do not need to be *exactly* one way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to do your own animations, you might want to search for *Essential graphics presets*. Essential graphics allows you to load AE compositions inside PP ready to edit like the ones you have seen. There are a bunch of places where you can get them, for free and paid, like Envato Elements, Premiumbeat, Mixkit, even Youtube itself.

If you want to know more about it, here's a link to Adobe's wiki for "Essential Graphics": https://helpx.adobe.com/es/premiere-pro/how-to/essential-graphics-panel.html

Comment: I noticed that the rendering is very very very slow. Hours for a 5 minute video. is that normal or did I just get a bad one?